# Why is react-router-dom <Redirect> not working?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Just trying to simply redirect once authenticated. figured i would convert my login screen to class component because i had a condition to redirect that was causing an endless loop. however once i converted my login screen, the redirect wasnt working at all. Im using react-router-dom v5.2...i read someone say that redirect isnt a part of v5+ and it changed to 'Navigate'...but it definitely was working at one point. and plus when trying to use 'Navigate' it says its not an exported package.

here the login screen:

```
class LoginScreen extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            username: '',
            password: '',
            password2: '',
            role: '',
            email: ''
        }
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
        if (this.props.isAuthenticated) {
            console.log("Logged in")
            return (<Redirect to={'/dashboard'} />)
        }
    }

    render() {
        const { email, role, password, password2, username } = this.state
        return (
            <$.Container>
                <$.Wrapper>
                    <$.Logo />
                    <$.Form>
                        <$.Input
                            type="email"
                            value={email}
                            placeholder="Email"
                            onChange={e => this.setState({ email: e.target.value })}
                        />
                        <$.Input
                            type="username"
                            value={username}
                            placeholder="Username"
                            onChange={e => this.setState({ username: e.target.value })}
                        />
                        <$.Input
                            type="password"
                            value={password}
                            placeholder="Password"
                            onChange={e => this.setState({ password: e.target.value })}
                        />
                        <$.Input
                            type="password"
                            value={password2}
                            placeholder="Password Confirm"
                            onChange={e => this.setState({ password2: e.target.value })}
                        />
                        <$.Input
                            type="role"
                            value={role}
                            placeholder="Role"
                            onChange={e => this.setState({ role: e.target.value })}
                        />
                    </$.Form>
                    <$.Button onClick={() => this.props.login(email, password)}>Sign In</$.Button>
                    <$.Button onClick={() => this.props.register({ email, password, password2, role, username })}>Register</$.Button>

                    {this.props.message != null ?
                        this.props.error ?
                            <$.Error>{this.props.message}</$.Error>
                            : <$.Info>{this.props.message}</$.Info>
                        : null}
                </$.Wrapper>
            </$.Container >
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ auth }) => {
    const { isAuthenticated, message, error } = auth
    return { isAuthenticated, message, error }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = { login, register }

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LoginScreen)
```

the condtion passes, as the log statement is output. but the redirect isnt redirecting.

heres app.js render:

```
<Provider store={store}>
  <Router>
    <div className="App">
      <Switch>
        {routes.map((route, index) => (
          route.private ?
            <PrivateRoute exact={route.exact} path={route.path} component={route.main} key={index} />
            :
            <Route exact={route.exact} path={route.path} component={route.main} key={index} />))}
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </Router>
</Provider>
```

page redirected to:

```
import React from 'react'

function DashboardScreen(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>dashboard screen</h1>
    </div>
  )
}

export default DashboardScreen
```

privateRoute component:

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'
import Sidebar from '../components/navigation/Sidebar'

function PrivateRoute({ component: Component, ...rest }) {

    return (
        <Route {...rest} render={(props) => props.isAuthenticated ? (
            <div style={{ display: 'grid', gridTemplateColumns: '200px auto' }}>
                <Sidebar role={'super-admin'} />
                <Component role={'test-role'} {...props} />
            </div>
        ) : (
                <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/', state: { referrer: props.location } }} />
            )}
        />
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ auth }) => {
    const { isAuthenticated } = auth
    return { isAuthenticated }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PrivateRoute)
```

how can i get this redirect working?

Answer (score 4):

You need to put the `Redirect` in JSX that is going to be rendered. `componentDidUpdate` is not going to render that returned value. So instead, remove `componentDidUpdate` and change the top of your `render` to:

```
    render() {
        const { isAuthenticated } = this.props;
        const { email, role, password, password2, username } = this.state;

        if (isAuthenticated) {
            return (<Redirect to={'/dashboard'} />);
        }

        return (
            ...
```

Comment: after having done this, im getting `Error: Maximum update depth exceeded...` error

Comment: That sounds like your have a redirect loop. Is the component you've shown rendered on `/dashboard`? If so, that is probably the problem. Or it could be `/dashboard` has a `Redirect` on it too? It's hard to debug such loops without all the details.

Comment: I didnt think I did but ill take a deeper look

Comment: I added the screen redirected to, and the private route component. I dont see the loop...

Comment: @Jim Unfortunately, you're getting to something complex enough that you have to post a full broken example. I suspect somehow you're rendering the Login screen somewhere else. From my answer above, you could try changing the return to be `return (<div>I'd redirect now</div>);` and see if that changes the behavior (and if you see it on `/dashboard` -- I'd inspect the DOM).